# gitignore failing to ignore .pyc files in library

Tags: git, gitignore, pyc

My gitignore has the following lines

```
__init__.cpython-36.pyc
functions.cpython-36.pyc
.DS_Store
__pycache__
*.pyc
```

But my git client is still registering changes to the pyc files

[image]

After reading online I just don't understand what my problem is. Any ideas? Let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file was already tracked before you created `.gitignore`. In that
case you need to untrack it:

```
git rm --cached ...
```

From `man git-rm`:

> --cached
>
> ```
>        Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the
>        index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be
>        left alone.
> ```